# How to set href to some value if I have <a id='view.php'>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get time in miliseconds and attach that on  like get parameter on 'view.php'. How to set href to that value ( `href='view.php?time=x`) if I have `<a id='view.php'>` using JQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will set the href of a link with id `link-id` to a UTC value of UNIXTIME:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#link-id").attr("href", "view.php?time=" + ((new Date()).getTime() + (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 ))});
```

Edit: Fixed code and wording.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#yourElementId").attr("href", "view.php?time=" + (new Date()).getTime())
```

Comment: Note that using this, you will get the local time of the user browsing your site.

Comment: Thanks Till's comment. And also thanks Nanne for editing my comment. I am a new guy to StackOverflow, sorry for answer without format.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
<div id="target">
    <a id="view.php">link</a>
    <a id="anotherview.php">link</a>
</div>
```

You can:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
$("#target a").each(function() {
    this.href = this.id + "?time=" + time;
});
```

Result:

```
<div id="target">
    <a id="view.php" href="view.php?time=1308729633979">link</a>
    <a id="anotherview.php" href="anotherview.php?time=1308729633979">link</a>
</div>
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/njqYy/). (And [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/njqYy/4/) where links without IDs are not changed.)